# postgres prepare query, columns as variable

Tags: postgresql, go

```
    var SelectUser, _ = Database.Prepare("SELECT $1 FROM users WHERE id=$2 LIMIT 1;")
    var name string
    SelectUser.QueryRow("name", 1).Scan(&name)
```

If i do like that i got an error:

> runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

But if column is not variable, all ok.

```
var SelectUser, _ = Database.Prepare("SELECT name FROM users WHERE id=$1 LIMIT 1;")
var name string
SelectUser.QueryRow(1).Scan(&name)
```

How can I pass columns as variables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Golang ORDER BY issue with MySql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30867337/golang-order-by-issue-with-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are ignoring the error of the `Database.Prepare` statement. If you check the error you will realise, that it fails preparing the sql. The reason why it fails was already answered here by [icza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1705598/icza):

[Golang ORDER BY issue with MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30867337/golang-order-by-issue-with-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Effectively , you can't use variable as field name in a query , you have to pass by a dynamic query.

Try creating a function :

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getFieldFromUserById(field_name character varying, id_user integer)
   RETURNS SETOF character varying AS
   $BODY$begin
      return query execute 'SELECT '||field_name||' FROM users  WHERE nart='||id_user||' LIMIT 1';
end
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

and your code :

```
var SelectUser, _ = Database.Prepare("SELECT getFieldFromUserById($1,$2 );")
var name string
SelectUser.QueryRow("name", 1).Scan(&name)
```