# Postgres could not determine data type of parameter $1 in Golang application

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, go, pq

I am creating an application in Golang that uses Postgres using the pq driver. I want to make a function that can select a user-determined field from my database, but I get an error:

> pq: could not determine data type of parameter $1

Below is the code that generated this error:

```
var ifc interface{}

if err := conn.QueryRow("SELECT $1 FROM "+db+" WHERE uuid=$3 OR uri=$4 LIMIT 1", field, UUIDOrURI, UUIDOrURI).Scan(&ifc); err != nil {
    if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
        return http.StatusNotFound
    }

    log.Println(err)

    return http.StatusInternalServerError
}
```

Why can I not insert the field that I want to  `SELECT` using `$1`? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of [Golang ORDER BY issue with MySql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30867337/golang-order-by-issue-with-mysql).

Comment: maybe you should perform a type cast  as explained here: https://github.com/jackc/pgx/issues/281#issuecomment-307247685

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use placeholders for field names. You'll have to build the query directly, as in:

```
"SELECT `" + field + "` FROM "
```

To avoid SQL injections, make sure that the field is part of a list of allowed fields beforehand.

Comment: I figured that is one method to do this, but that would require me to make a list of field names in the database, which is a hassle to update every time I update a field in the database. Is there not another way to do it using a placeholder instead?

Comment: You can apply a regex and make sure only valid characters are allowed.

Comment: You can also get the list of valid fields using something like this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/22368/37012 Then maybe cache the result of this query so that you can refer to it as needed.

Answer (score -3):

IMHO an easier way, but not safe, to create SQL queries is to use fmt.Sprintf:

```
query := fmt.Sprintf("SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE uuid=%s", field, db, UUIDOrURI)
if err := conn.QueryRow(query).scan(&ifc); err != nil {

}
```

You can even specify an argument index:

```
query := fmt.Sprintf("SELECT %[2]s FROM %[1]s", db, field)
```

In order to ease the development, I recommend to use a package for the postgresql communication, I tried [this one](https://github.com/go-gorp/gorp) and worked great.

Comment: _Easiest_ does not imply _safest_. Package `fmt` has no knowledge of and does not attempt to prevent any SQL injection attacks.

Comment: I didn't mean it to be safe, just answered the question "Is there another way to do this?".

Comment: @Jean-NicolasMoal and probably you made someone lost his job, lol :D

Comment: https://xkcd.com/327/