# Golang database/sql.DB.QueryRow with multiple args

Tags: mysql, database, go

I want to execute a query something like this (using MySql):

```
select * from user where id = 5
```

Ex 1. This returns `err = sql.ErrNoRows`:

```
err := db.QueryRow("select * from user where ? = ?", f, v).Scan(&user.Id, etc...)
```

Ex 2. Since the above doesn't work, I am doing it this way, which works but doesn't feel right:

```
err := db.QueryRow("select * from user where "+f+" = ?", v).Scan(&user.Id, etc...)
```

What is wrong in Ex. 1? Is Ex 2. an acceptable way to do this?

EDIT

From the link in the comments I can do it a third way.

Ex 3:

```
q := fmt.Sprintf("select * from user where %s = ?", f)
err := db.QueryRow(q, v).Scan(&user.Id, etc...)
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of [Golang ORDER BY issue with MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30867337/golang-order-by-issue-with-mysql/30867686#30867686).

Comment: Whether `WHERE ? = ?` works depends on your database driver, and what each `?` represents. In the DBs I'm familiar with (Postgres, MySQL, and SQLite), you can use variable substitution only for values, not for column names. This means if `f` is your column name, your second try (and equivalent third) is not only "right", but the only option.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide column names directly in sql query. '?' sign is a placeholder for values you provide after sql string.
Your Ex3. is correct, but it is not a good solution, because it is open for SQL-injection attacks.

If you need a lightweight solution you can create a map with known column names for each table like: `userColumns := map[string]bool {"id": true, ...}` and then just use next check:

```
if userColumns[f] {
    ...you able to use f in sql...
} else {
    ...provided value is not one of known columns, it is an error...
}
```